# “Selector does not match selector syntax” when passing Thymeleaf fragment as argument to another fragment

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to have a shared template for all pages, which will have, e.g. a green frame to be posted on an every page. And I have an index page which has a blue frame. So I create `fragments/whole_page.html` with fragment `whole_page`, which is called from `pages/index.html` with `~{::index_page_content}` as a fragment argument:

```java
//controllers/TaskController.java

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TaskController {
    private final TasksService tasksService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("tasks", tasksService.getAllTasks());
        return "pages/index";
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- templates/pages/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
        lang="en"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        th:replace="~{ fragments/whole_page.html :: whole_page(~{ :: index_page_content}}"
>
<div
    th:fragment="index_page_content"
    style="margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 2px solid blue;"
>
    <p th:if="${tasks.size() == 0}">
        No tasks stored at the moment
    </p>
    <p th:if="${tasks.size() > 0}">
        There are <th:block th:text="${tasks.size()}" /> tasks stored at the moment
    </p>
</div>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- templates/fragments/whole_page.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="whole_page(content)">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 2px solid green;">
        <th:block th:replace="${content}" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I request this page, I got an error message in console:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid syntax in selector "whole_page(~{ :: #indexPageContent}": selector does not match selector syntax: ((/|//)?selector)?([@attrib="value" ((and|or) @attrib2="value")?])?([index])?
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've made a syntax error. This way it works:

````html
<!-- templates/pages/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
        lang="en"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        th:replace="~{fragments/whole_page.html :: whole_page(~{ :: indexPageContent})}"
>
<div th:fragment="indexPageContent" style="margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 2px solid blue;">
    <p th:if="${tasks.size() == 0}">
        No tasks stored at the moment
    </p>
    <p th:if="${tasks.size() > 0}">
        There are <th:block th:text="${tasks.size()}" /> tasks stored at the moment
    </p>
</div>
</html>```
````